# Ubuntu Cabal build undefined reference z3 error

Tags: ubuntu, haskell, z3, cabal

I've just installed Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, I'm trying to run [this](https://gitlab.fing.edu.uy/matefun/MateFun) haskell project, I don´t need to actually edit it, but I need to run it to be able to use it for college.

I follow the steps specified in the readme:

```
$ apt-get install -y ghc cabal-install git gettext locales

$ wget https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/releases/download/z3-4.6.0/z3-4.6.0-x64-ubuntu-16.04.zip
$ unzip z3-4.6.0-x64-ubuntu-16.04.zip 
$ cp z3-4.6.0-x64-ubuntu-16.04/bin/libz3.so /usr/lib/ 
$ cp z3-4.6.0-x64-ubuntu-16.04/bin/z3 /usr/bin/ 
$ cp z3-4.6.0-x64-ubuntu-16.04/include/* /usr/include/
```

```
$ git clone https://gitlab.fing.edu.uy/matefun/MateFun.git

$ cd MateFun/
$ cabal update
$ cabal install happy
$ cabal install hgettext
```

The I run into a problem when trying to `$ cabal install z3` because

```
cabal: Cannot build the executables in the package z3 because none of the
components are available to build: the executable 'examples' is marked as
'buildable: False'
```

I got over this by doing `cabal install z3 --lib` instead.

But then I tried doing `cabal build` and this is where I got stuck as I get

```
(...)
[14 of 14] Compiling Main  
error: undefined reference to 'Z3_optimize_assert_and_track'
error: undefined reference to 'Z3_optimize_get_unsat_core'
```

Been trying to find what the problem could be, tried adding `--extra-lib-dirs=/usr/bin/ --extra-include-dirs=/usr/include/` but id didn´t make a difference.

Any idea on how to make it work? I'm trying here but it's really not my strong suit

Comment: The fact that the tutorial suggests `cabal install z3` is a red flag. You should basically _never_ install packages manually. Either Cabal figures out by itself that the package is needed as a dependency, and automatically installs it, or else it also won't help that you've already installed it.

Comment: For another thing, why should you manually install the z3 prover? I would at least give it a try first with `sudo apt install libz3-dev`, if that doesn't work look for a ppa, and only if nothing else works start manually putting stuff in `/usr`.

Comment: Thanks everyone! `sudo apt install libz3-dev` after deleting what I had manually added seems to work fine! Iḿ not sure if I can mark a comment as the correct answer though?